# How can I add click event to onBackPressed in Fragment?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-fragments, buttonclick

I want to add on-click listener to onBackPressed() button. How can I do that?

fun onBackPressed(it: View) {

```
        val title = binding.edittexttitle.text
        val notes = binding.edittextnote.text

        val d = Date()
        val s: CharSequence = DateFormat.format("MMMM d, yyyy ", d.time)

        Log.e("@@@@@", "createNotes: $s")

    }
```

Answer (score 7):

To override `onBackPressed` in `fragment` call `onBackPressedDispatcher` of the `activity` and add a `callback` to it. In callback put whatever code you want to be get executed on the back button press.

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    
    val title = binding.edittexttitle.text
    val notes = binding.edittextnote.text

    val d = Date()
    val s: CharSequence = DateFormat.format("MMMM d, yyyy ", d.time)

    Log.e("@@@@@", "createNotes: $s")
}
```

Afterwards if you want the `back button` to work as it normally does, just disable `callback` using `isEnabled = false` and then call `requireActivity().onBackPressed()`, inside callback lambda.

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
    // Your code
    isEnabled = false
    requireActivity().onBackPressed()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **This one is working for me in fragment**

```
requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            findNavController().navigateUp() // to clear previous navigation history
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_transactionHistoryFragment_to_DashboardFragment)

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override handleOnBackPressed.

```
override fun handleOnBackPressed() {
            binding.yourbutton.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Actually, I want to add the listener with Back Button. When anyone will press the back button so that the information can be saved automatically

Comment: Okey; binding.yourbutton.setOnClickListener {
            //TODO
        } Did not work this?